# Use `ld -r` and get compilation errors if symbols are missing

Tags: c, gcc, ld, position-independent-code

I've recently begun using [a new ELF loader](https://github.com/martinribelotta/elfloader). The loader requires you to link your applications with `ld -r`.

The problem is that GCC no longer warns me of undefined functions, and then the loader (obviously) fails to find them.

How do I link with `ld -r`, and get the undefined symbols method.

I am using `ld -r` for relocation purposes, so a different way to include relocations will also work for me.

Comment: I guess you could perform one link phase without the -r symbol, to a temporary, unused .elf file, and if it succeeds proceed to the real one.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so you mean link twice? I guess I could do that.

Comment: if it's doesn't take too much time. Else, I would need a [mcve] to try to do it in one pass.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think that your method will work. Post it as an answer and I'll accept if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your makefile, define an intermediate target where you link with all the options *but* the `-r` one, to a file in the temporary directory (so you're sure not to use it).

If this phase succeeds, then proceed to the real link with the `-r` option.

Comment: Thank you for your help.